# Listar array dentro de excessões (IF) e gerar novo array de status

Tags: php, array

Criei um algoritmo que verifica um array de porcentagens e retorna um status de acordo com o valor, porém meu array **STATUS** está me retornando apenas o último valor. Eu gostaria que o array status recebesse todos os valores dentro dele, por exemplo `$percentinstalled[0] = 50`, então `$status[0] = 'critical'`, e assim por diante...

```
<?php

$percentinstalled = array(
    0=>'50.0',
    1=>'93.1',
    2=>'100.0',
    3=>'75.2',
    4=>'69.0',
    5=>'100.0',
    6=>'96.7',
    7=>'38.7',
    8=>'22.7',
    9=>'91.6',
    10=>'33.3',
    11=>'100.0',
    12=>'96.9',
    13=>'54.3',
    14=>'67.2',
    15=>'81.9'
);

$status = array();

for ($j = 0; $j <= 15; $j++) {
    if ($percentinstalled[$j] >= 98.0) {
        $status = array(
            $j => "ok",
        );
    } elseif ($percentinstalled[$j] >= 95.0) {
        $status = array(
            $j => "warning",
        );
    } elseif ($percentinstalled[$j] >= 80.0) {
        $status = array(
            $j => "alert",
        );
    } elseif ($percentinstalled[$j] <= 79.9) {
        $status = array(
            $j => "critical",
        );
    } else {
        $status = array(
            $j => "Unknow",
        );
    }

}

foreach ($status as &$val3) {
    echo $val3 . "</br>";
}

?>
```

[VISUALIZAR CÓDIGO](https://paiza.io/projects/StOVM0VuR40gcmlGGltEMA)

**OBJETIVO:**

Eu tenho o array `$percentinstalled` com todos os valores em `float`, gostaria de passar todos esses valores dentro de um `IF` onde de acordo com esses valores ele me retorne o que foi definido dentro dessa excessão, que nosso caso seria uma `string` onde o valor pode ser: (ok para >= 98.0, warning para >= 95.0, alert para >= 80.0, critical para <= 79.9 ou unknow caso nenhum valor seja encontrado). Da forma atual ele está apenas salvando o último valor do array **(posição 15)**, e não todos os valores como desejado.

Comment: não entendi bem o que quer fazer, pode explicar melhor? quer passar um par de valores para o array?

Comment: Eu tenho o array `$percentinstalled` com todos os valors em `float`, gostaria de passar todos esses valores dentro de um `IF` onde de acordo esse valor ele me retorne o que foi definido dentro dessa excessão, que nosso caso seria um `string` com o valor de: (ok, warning, alert, critical ou unknow). Da forma atual ele está apenas salvando o último valor do array **(posição 15)**, e não todos os valores como desejado.

Comment: Troca o `$status = array($j => "")` por `$status[] = array($j => "texto")`. Assim você vai concatenar os valores. **Ou**, simplesmente: `$status[$j] = "texto"`

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, o que você quer fazer é simples, basta você atribuir o `status` setando a posição do `array`.

```
$status = [];
// Usei o count para pegar o tamanho total do array e não precisar "setar" diretamente
for ($j = 0; $j <= count($percentinstalled); $j++) {  
    if ($percentinstalled[$j] >= 98.0) {
        $status[$j] =  "ok";
    } elseif ($percentinstalled[$j] >= 95.0) {
        $status[$j] = "warning";
    } elseif ($percentinstalled[$j] >= 80.0) {
        $status[$j] = "alert";
    } elseif ($percentinstalled[$j] <= 79.9) {
        $status[$j] = "critical";
    } else {
        $status[$j] = "Unknow";
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o `array` status vai ficar assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => critical
    [1] => alert
    [2] => ok
    [3] => critical
    [4] => critical
    [5] => ok
    [] => warning
    [7] => critical
    [8] => critical
    [9] => alert
    [10] => critical
    [11] => ok
    [13] => critical
    [14] => critical
    [15] => alert
)
```

Comment: opa, muito obrigado, deu certo aqui :)

Answer (score 3):

A operação que você precisa fazer é mapeamento. Converter um valor da entrada em um valor na saída e como o próprio nome diz, pode utilizar a função `array_map`.

Crie uma função de conversão:

```php
function setStatusByPercentValue($value) {
    if ($value >= 98.0) return 'ok';
    if ($value >= 95.0) return 'warning';
    if ($value >= 80.0) return 'alert';
    return 'critical';
}
```

E depois faça:

```
$status = array_map('setStatusByPercentValue', $percentinstalled);
```

Para a entrada dada na pergunta a saída seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => critical
    [1] => alert
    [2] => ok
    [3] => critical
    [4] => critical
    [5] => ok
    [6] => warning
    [7] => critical
    [8] => critical
    [9] => alert
    [10] => critical
    [11] => ok
    [12] => warning
    [13] => critical
    [14] => critical
    [15] => alert
)
```